# How to quickly select edge loop around grid filled area?

Tags: modeling, edges

I've been trying to figure out a way to quickly select the edge loop / ring around an area I have just grid filled. If I 'alt + click' the edge ring it only partially selects. I appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: If I use an ngon instead of grid fill, it will allow me to retain control of that edge. Later I can convert that ngon to triangles using 'ctrl + T', then convert to quads using 'alt + J'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. select an outer ring

[image]

2. expand the selection towards the ring around the grid fill

[image]

3. deselect all but the ring around the grid fill, using <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd> and right click on the outer ring. In your example the above selection expansion will need then to deselect 2 outer rings, I guess.

[image]

Comment: Haha, wanted to post the same answer, but then realized it requires 4 steps to do it. So it's probably easier and faster to just select the circle with 4 *Alt+Shift+RMB* actions :).

Comment: yes, you're right. I just came up with another way which is not really faster, but (arguably) more elegant though... :D